What do we call a Poisson point process with an instantaneous log-rate being a Wiener process?
I have implemented a stochastic process for simulating demand of service that wanders in its average rate. This is a useful scenario for evaluating a controller that tries to optimize availability and scheduling of servers at a service.
For a brief description we have for $0 \leq a < b$
$$\alpha_a^b = \int_a^b \lambda(t)\ dt$$
where $\log \lambda(t)$ is a Wiener process and $\alpha_a^b$ is the mean for a Poisson point process.
I'm having the usual problem that when you come up with something on your own you have no idea what the literature calls it. It also seems implausible to me that I'm the first to think of this mathematical model. How is it referred to in the academic literature?
